# Is it a bad idea to give a user sudo access to perl?

Tags: linux, perl, security, sudo

Is it a bad idea to give a user sudo access to perl (or any programming language interpreter for that matter)

E.g., it lets the user do this:

```
sudo perl -e 'print `cat /etc/sudoers`'
```

when they can't just do a

```
cat /etc/sudoers
```

Or is there something I'm missing which can prevent this? (I'm assuming not...)

Comment: Considering that you can execute shell commands with Perl, this is another way of giving them root access. So yes, it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give sudo access to any interpreter (all programming languages and all shells) then that user can do anything he wants on the system. So yes, it is a very bad idea.

Similar bad ideas include giving sudo access to `rm`, `mv`, `tee` or any archiving program (like `tar` or `zip`).

This question is also not about programming but about system management and therefore better suited to e.g. SuperUser.